# find the computer name of for the login specified

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have C#.Net code that return info from Active Directory as follows:

```
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://MYServer");
        DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

        String Name = name;
        string restulted = "";

        Dsearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(displayName=" + Name + "))";

        foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in Dsearch.FindAll())
        {

            restulted = GetProperty(sResultSet, "cn").ToString();

            // First Name
            // myLabel.Text=myLabel.Text+ GetProperty(sResultSet, "sAMAccountName").ToString();

            // Last Name
            restulted = restulted + "*" + GetProperty(sResultSet, "profilePath").ToString();
            restulted = restulted + "*" + GetProperty(sResultSet, "computer").ToString();

            if (GetProperty(sResultSet, "lastLogon") != null)
            {

                long lastlogontimestamp = (long)sResultSet.Properties["lastlogontimestamp"][0]; 
                DateTime dtLastLoginTimeStamp = DateTime.FromFileTime(lastlogontimestamp);
                restulted = restulted + "*" + dtLastLoginTimeStamp.ToString();
            }
```

The Above code does not return the computer the user is logged in or last logged in. How do I get the computer/computers the user is currently logged in or if not logged in the last logged on computer name???

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory doesn't store which computer the user last logged on.

I have seen product gathering event logs from domain controllers to determine which computer the user most recently logon.